# Exercise package: Roman characters in Question command

Tags: numbering, exercises

I'm not sure if this is the most modern exercise package... but I would in the exercise package for LaTeX, I would like to redefine the `\Question` command so that it returns roman characters e.g. (a) & (b) rather than arabic numerals e.g. 1. & 2.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{ExerciseList}
  \Exercise{Test exercise}
  \Question{Test question}
  \Question{Test question 2}
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

If there are more recent exercise packages with more functionality or which are better supported then that would also be good to know

Comment: For exercise packages: https://www.ctan.org/topic/exercise

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{\alph{Question}.\ }` but I don't know about collateral consequences.

Comment: If there are references to questions you'd also want to do `\renewcommand{\theQuestion}{\alph{Question}}`.

Comment: Thank you both! I tried doing this before but thought I had to change the \Question command to \QuestionNB as well. A bit counterintuitively, I'm supposed to leave it as \Question. Not sure exactly what's going on under the hood there